# Braintree v2 getting nonce with a post back to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, braintree

I am trying to get the nonce string from "v2/braintree.js". How do i trigger on a post back to the server on a link button click to generate the nonce string? I would like to retrieve it this way:

```
Request.Form["payment_method_nonce"].ToString();
```

In the old version "v1/braintree.js" i used the following when a button was clicked.

```
function submit_data() {
            var braintree = Braintree.create('------key-------');
            braintree.encryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
        }
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. Your question is a little hard to understand. Your best bet is to [get in touch with the Braintree support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if [the Braintree docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/start/overview) aren't answering your questions.

Comment: I apologize if my question is confusing. I have found the answer though to my question. The problem too was that I did not see a non MVC sample on Braintree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wanted to access the nonce string on a post back and validate all the fields on a post back i used the following. The problem I was having is that the nonce string was computed asynchronously.

I created

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="nonce_hidden" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Then on link button to purchase I did this

```
<a href="#!" class="button" onclick="get_nonce_data();">Purchase</a>
```

Then i created a link button that was not visible that posts back to the server when clicked.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="cc_payment_next_btn" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" OnClick="cc_payment_next_btn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The "Purchase" link launches the script to tokenize the credit card info and saves the nonce string to a hidden value. Once the nonce string is computed it triggers 'click' on the hidden link button that I have that posts back to the server.

```
function get_nonce_data() {var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name_txt").value;var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name_txt").value;var zip_code = document.getElementById("zip_code_txt").value;var client = new braintree.api.Client({ clientToken: "client-token" });client.tokenizeCard({number: document.getElementById("cc_number_txt").value,cardholderName: first_name + ' ' + last_name,expirationDate: document.getElementById("cc_expiration_txt").value,cvv: document.getElementById("cc_ccv_txt").value,billingAddress: {postalCode: zip_code}}, function (err, nonce) {if (err === null) {document.getElementById("nonce_hidden").value = nonce;$('#cc_payment_next_btn')[0].click();}else {alert('An error has occured');}});}
```

All the validation and processing then is done on the back end.